# What function has these integer results?

Tags: python, modular-arithmetic

For example, I have a reference number `a = 15` and `b= 3`.

- If `x=2`, `f(a,b,x) = 1` because if one divide 15 into 3 parts, the number 2 is in the first part.
- If `x=7`, `f(a,b,x) = 2` because if one divide 15 into 3 parts, the number 7 is in the second part.
- If `x=15`, `f(a,b,x) = 3` because if one divide 15 into 3 parts, the number 15 is in the third part.
- If x<0 or >15 the results are irrelevant to me.

Is there any built-in function like this?

Comment: You could subtract `x` from `a` and divide by `b` (truncated), I think you'd get your answer, except zero-indexed.

Comment: What is the answer for `x=5`?

Comment: And what is the answer for `x=0`?

Comment: Four upvotes for question about simple arithmetic  one-liner? Really?

Comment: If x <= (a//b)*c the answer is c.

That is, if x <= 5*1, the answer is 1. If x <= 5*2, it's 2 and so on.

Comment: So for `x = 0` the answer is `0`.

Comment: aga, the question is about a built-in function and not about how to write a function.

Comment: @DavidSousa And where does the `b` come into play?

Comment: @David: That's a resource request and off-topic then; and not all that useful a question to answer. Such a function is not commonly needed in general Python programming, nor is it a common function in mathematics. Why would you expect it to be built-in?

Comment: @Hyperboreus I've edited the comment up there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that function seems useful to me, so I expected that it would exist.

Comment: @DavidSousa: Many functions are useful to many, but still not generally applicable.

Answer (score 7):

I can't think of a single built-in function which would do exactly that. It is however not difficult to write one:

```
def f(a, b, x):
  return (x - 1) * b // a + 1

for i in range(1, 16):
  print i, f(15, 3, i)
```

This prints out

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 2
7 2
8 2
9 2
10 2
11 3
12 3
13 3
14 3
15 3
```

(It is not entirely clear from the question how, and if, `x=0` needs to be handled; this answer considers it to be outside the valid range.)

Comment: Thank you, it works like expected.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such built-in function.  You can certainly write your own, however.

Comment: Although true, this could have been a comment; why not *write that function*? As it stands, this isn't very helpful.

Comment: OP didn't ask for a function definition; explicitly asked for a built-in one.  Thus, this is PRECISELY answering the question as asked.

Comment: Yup, but that means, in my experience, that the OP is really asking for such a function. If there is no such function, *why* isn't there; is it impossible to write it? Etc. A simple 'no, there is not' is rarely actually helpful.

Comment: And yet the author comments above "aga, the question is about a built-in function and not about how to write a function."